# how to show a auto suggest div box over other elements

Tags: php, mysql, css, ajax

i am new to css .. i can easily fetch the suggestions from the back end to the suggestion div.

Height of suggestion div is set to `height:auto` as it is adjusted automatically depending on the suggestion as shown

```
<div class="suggestBox">
     <div class="suggestionsBox" style="margin-left:16px">
     <div class="suggestions bordered" style="height: auto; max-height: none; width:100%; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; ">
      <div class="jspContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 0px; ">
      <div class="jspPane" style="padding: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; ">
    <div class="items_block"></div>
    <div class="users_block"></div>
    </div>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

but as it's height is altered i.e grown .. the elements under the suggestion box or div are scattered or something like that ... do i have to change something in CSS ..

```
//THANX
```

Comment: Have you considered using jQuery UI? http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: To have content over certain elements, I guess you could use CSS `z-index`.

Answer (score 0):

For maintaining depth of layers in CSS there is `z-index` property.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving it `position:absolute;` to remove it from the document layout.
See this tutorial: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/